# I don't get why my component is called twice in this example

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I've been following the complete react native and redux guide on Udemy and there is this part where despite following down to a tee. My LibraryList component still gets called twice. 
What could be the problem?

LibraryList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LibraryList extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    libraries: state.libraries
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import LibraryList from './components/LibraryList';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Header headerText='Tech Stack' />
        <LibraryList />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

LibraryReducer.js

```
import data from './LibraryList.json';

export default () => data;
```

index.js inside reducers folder

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import LibraryReducer from './LibraryReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  libraries: LibraryReducer
});
```

LibraryList.json

```
[
{"id": 0,
"title": "Webpack",
"description": "Webpack is a module bundler. It packs CommonJs/AMD modules i. e. for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand."
},
....
]
```

Expected result: console.log(this.props) runs once and return libraries

Actual result: It runs twice

Comment: interesting. did you see your props were the same in both times?

Comment: I think this can be helpful for debugging: https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#component-update-monitoring

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with one of my projects.

In `LibraryList.js` instead of extending `Component` use `PureComponent`. PureComponents won't call the render function if the state and the props have not changed, since it integrates a simple check in the `shouldComponentUpdate` method. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

You could always implements your own `shouldComponentUpdate` method with a React `Component` instead of using the `PureComponent`. You'll need to be careful when implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method with Redux, you may create more bugs. https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-isn-t-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running

When I tried your example on Android and iOS, I wasn't able to replicate your issue, it only returned once.